# Using Python to Replace Image in Powerpoint

Tags: python, vba, image, replace, powerpoint

I want to be able to replace some images in some PowerPoint presentations I have programmatically. I'm partial to python since its what I know best but I am open to other solutions. The only python package that I found that seems relevant is: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#user-guide. However, I haven't found anything that says that images can be deleted from it. My attempts so far haven't been successful, so if anyone has any ideas on how to do that through this package I would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: An image is just a shape. Not strong in `python-pptx` but I do think it's easy to delete/add shapes.

Comment: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/shp-picture.html

Comment: @BigBen Adding shapes isn't the problem, its replacing/removing the existing one that I haven't seen anything on just yet.

Comment: Got it. If it turns out to be too hard in python-pptx, it's probably pretty easy in VBA.

Comment: If you search Google on `python-pptx replace image` you'll find others who have asked and answered this question. It's not easy, but it can be done. There are issues related to scaling and size that need to be addressed. Just replacing the image might not be enough to get something that looks good.